# CSS Selector for all dd elements under a dt element

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, screen-scraping

### Problem

Is it possible to grab all `dd` elements under a specific `dt` element?

Specifically, I am trying to capture the `dd` elements under the `dt` element titled '*Life Cycle*' on this page: https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/abeliophyllum-distichum/

I want to capture '*Life Cycle*' for other plant pages too, where they could have 1 or more `dd` elements under the `dt` for '*Life Cycle*'. So I need a CSS selector that could work for the scenario of 1 or more `dd` elements.

Here is what the HTML structure looks like:

```
<dl>
    <span>Attributes:</span>
        <dt>Life Cycle:</dt>
            <dd><span>Perennial</span></dd>
            <dd><span>Woody</span></dd>
        <dt>Text:</dt>
                <dd><span>Text</span></dd>
        <dt>Text:</dt>
                <dd><span>Text</span></dd>
       <dt>Text:</dt>
       <dd><span>Text</span></dd>
       <dd><span>Text</span></dd>
</dl>
```

### What I've tried

1. `dt:contains('Life Cycle:') + dd`

This only returns the first `dd` element

[image]

2. `dt:contains('Life Cycle:') ~ dd`

This returns all of the `dd` elements after the `dt` even `dd`s under other `dt`s.

[image]

3. I wish I could use n-child like `dt:contains('Life Cycle:'):nth-child(-n+2)`, but I can't because `dd` elements aren't children of `dt`s.

### What I need

I need something that is flexible for the scenario of having 1 or more `dd` elements under one `dt`. I am not able to modify the HTML, because I am scraping this data point from the website.

This is what I am trying to capture in my CSS selector:

[image]

Comment: this absolutely not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), never heard about it in more than 6 years here ?

Comment: Opps! @MisterJojo I thought that the URL link to the HTML would be best in this scenario. I added a simplified example of what the HTML structure looks like. It seems to meet the MRE requirements, but let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: What you need here is a selection method based on a preceding-sibling axis; unfortunately, css doesn't support that axis (only following-sibling). You may have to resort to using xpath instead.

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting I was worried that was the case. It looks like I'll have to scrape the full table, and then use regex to pull out the specific data that I need.

Comment: @marytay No, don't use regex on html/xml (web is full of explanations why...); that's what xpath is built for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks `:contains` css selecter only works in Selenium. In that case, you need something similar to `:not`, you can do the following:

```
dt:contains('Life Cycle:') ~ dd {
  color: red;
}

dt:contains('Life Cycle:') ~ dt ~ dd {
  color: black;
}
```

**Edit:** If you can't use css or xpath, then in jquery you can do the following:

```
$("dt:contains('Life Cycle:') ~ dd").css("color", "red");
$("dt:contains('Life Cycle:') ~ dt ~ dd").css("color", "black");
```

Comment: Hey @user31782 I appreciate the help, but I'm not able to modify the CSS directly. Instead I'm scraping a website and need to input the logic via a CSS selector in jQuery

Comment: @marytay see my latest edit.